# Why does my SDL window close when i return from an initializing function?

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

I have been working on a simple game engine (i know, i know, i've heard "Write games not engines" before, this is just to understand the concepts). I have been using SDL2, since it works well with OpenGL.  However for some reason, the program closes once the initializing function is completed.

```
Screen.cpp:
Screen::Screen(int width, int height, const std::string& title)
    {

        //Initialize SDL
        SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
        //Setting OpenGL Attributes
        SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_RED_SIZE, 8);
        SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_GREEN_SIZE, 8);
        SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_BLUE_SIZE, 8);
        SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_ALPHA_SIZE, 8);
        SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_BUFFER_SIZE, 32);
        SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);

        //Create the Window
        m_window = SDL_CreateWindow(title.c_str(), SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, width, height, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
        l.writeToDebugLog("Created SDL_Window!");
        //Create OpenGL context from within SDL
        m_glContext = SDL_GL_CreateContext(m_window);
        l.writeToDebugLog("Created SDL GL Context!");

        //Initializing GLEW
        GLenum status = glewInit();
        l.writeToDebugLog( "Initializing GLEW");
        if (status != GLEW_OK)
        {
                l.writeToGLEWELog(" Glew Failed to Initialize!");
        }

        //setting the windowSurface to the m_window's surface
        windowSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(m_window);
        m_isClosed = false;
    }
```

This is where i create the screen object and initialize all of the SDL functions and OpenGL functions

```
Engine.cpp:
        void Engine::initialize(){

        //Console Detecting platform
        c.initialize();
        //Printing Operating System to screen
        std::cout << "Loaded on : " << platformToString(c.os) << " OS " << std::endl;
        //Constructing a new Screen to be referenced too
        graphics::Screen temp(800,600,"ClimLib 0.0.05"); 

        //setting all the variables
        m_window = &temp;
        m_EntityManager = nullptr;
        m_isRunning = temp.isClosed();
        m_renderer = SDL_GetRenderer(m_window->getWindow());


    }
    void Engine::update(){
        do{
            //Check whether entities have been created and placed in the manager
            if (m_EntityManager != nullptr){
                for each(core::Entity *e in *m_EntityManager){
                    for each(core::Component *c in e->getComponentList()){
                        c->Update();
                    }
                }
            }


            //Update Logic Here
            m_window->Update();
            if (m_window->isClosed()){
                m_isRunning = false;
                return;
            }

            }while (isRunning());
        }
```

This initialize function is the last function my window executes before it deletes itself, maybe i need to call it from the main function of the program?

```
main.cpp:
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    clim::system::Engine game;
game.initialize();
while (game.isRunning()){
    game.update();
    }
return 0;
}
```

That is how i have my main set up at the moment.

**EDIT:**  I believe the reason was because i am creating a variable and storing it as a reference, when the function returns the temp variable is thrown away?

Comment: In  `Engine::initialize` you do `m_isRunning = temp.isClosed()` - now assuming the window is open at this point, this would be `false`, and assuming  `Engine::isRunning()` returns `m_isRunning` your `while(game.isRunning())` loop would terminate immediately.

Comment: i changed that up, but it was closing immediately after  game.initialize() - i set a breakpoint right after game.initialize() and it closed the window before once the breakpoint hit

Comment: Have you tried debugging, to see *why* your loop exits? Without knowing what isRunning() does exactly, it's hard to tell from this side of the internet :)

Comment: I just did, I dont understand why the window is deleting after it is returning from the initialize function, all the variables look correct

Comment: `temp` is a local variable that is destroyed when initialize returns, that might be why

Comment: i just thought of that and started on a work around haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating your screen as a temporary value and then assigning the address of that value to a pointer whose lifetime actually exceeds the lifetime of the value it's pointing to that is very likely a stack value as well. Short of your immediate issue with the window dying, this will cause one or both of the following when used later:

- Crashes (illegal memory access)
- Undefined behavior (from reading random values on the stack that are sitting at this address later in execution)

While perhaps not applicable now, this is a real good way to cause headaches for yourself in pretty much everything.

You should just assign like this:

```
 m_window = new graphics::Screen(800,600,"ClimLib 0.0.05");
```

The way you initialized it means that it will destroy itself when the function exits as it was declared and initialized in the function. 
Using new will guarantee it exists until you delete it because it will sit somewhere on the heap unmolested unless your code does.

Just make sure you call delete m_window in the destructor of the class containing it to properly clean up the window when you're done using it when using new to create it. You can also declare m_window to be a graphics::Screen instead of a graphics::Screen* and just assign m_window like:

```
m_window = graphics::Screen(800,600,"ClimLib 0.0.05");
```

This way you don't have to worry about deleting it yourself later as it will delete itself when the containing class is deleted.